# Old HTML Site to WordPress - Loss of SEO Rankings

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I have moved an old HTML site which had over 250 pages, nearly all of those pages were using the old trick of duplicating every page but just changing text to match the area where ranking was important.

The new site has been completed and been live for over a month now, this is what i have done:

1. Created necessary 301 redirects for ALL 250 pages, confirmed working.
2. Submitted sitemap to Google successfully
3. Checked for errors within the search console

The issue is that after a month of the site going live, the rankings from the old site seemed to have dramatically dropped, if not a total loss.

It became apparent that the new site seemed to have got infected with some rouge pages that had links to torrents, i fixed this pretty much as soon as i noticed but perhaps too late where google see this and rankings dropped because of it.

Is it just a case of waiting for Google to crawl the site again and be patient for rankings to come back up after the html to wordpress move?

I just want to find out if there's anything obvious I've done wrong here or perhaps forgot to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look into the google search console to see if there are problems or errors displayed there?

Comment: Yes, i have been checking in the search console daily. No problems there.

Comment: Is it at all possible that the rouge posts/links that the site got infected with caused this?

Comment: Yes, but Google won't  tell you anyway.  Tools like SEOBILITY can tell you more.